# Custom jQuery Tooltip: How to position it?

Tags: jquery

I've got a custom tooltip being pulled by Ajax, when you rollover a link, great...e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var tooltipId = this.hash; 
    $('#tooltip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).show();
}, function(){
    $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});});
</script>
```

So this shows the div... "tooltip-container"
But I think i'll need some further jQuery assistance in actually positioning the tooltip next to each element. As CSS isn't doing it...as it would dynamically need to be for each tooltip link hovered over.

So basically html is:

```
    <a href="#tip1" class="tippytrip">Show Tip 1</a><br />
    <a href="#tip2" class="tippytrip">Show Tip 2</a><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#tip1" class="tippytrip">Show Tip 1 - again</a>

<div id="tooltip-container"></div>
```

And then within tooltips.html I have:

```
<div id="tip1">
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
</div>
 <div id="tip2">
    <h1>Mr Tip 2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the CSS / HTML? You can absolutely position the tooltip to it's parent which has a `position:relative`. With an absolute position, you can then modify the top, bottom, right or left positions of the tooltip box, relative to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use jQuery's `.offset()` method to get the left and top positions of the `.tippytrip` link relative to the entire page.
2. Place the `#tooltip-container` completely outside of any other element (other than the `body`, of course), and position it absolutely, using the position data from #1 to position it correctly.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/5LSxG/

And here's the JS code. Pretty simple:

```
$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $('#tooltip-container').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});
```

I recommend going with the `.offset()` + "outside of any other element" combination because the alternative would be:

1. Use `.position()`, which gives the elements offset from its *nearest relatively positioned parent*.
2. Place the tooltip *within the same parent element* as the link. This is necessary so that the values you get from #1 are applied relative to the same element.

The problem with this is that simply re-positioning the tooltip wouldn't be enough. You'd also have to insert it into a different part of the DOM each time the relative parent of the link in question changes.

Comment: Lovely! - Any idea how to fade the tip in? And perhaps show a "loading .gif before content is loaded? - I think this could be it.

Comment: also...this isn't pulling the tooltips via ajax now :(

Comment: ok, sorted the ajax call with:

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
 var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
  var tooltipId = this.hash; // here you should dynamically assign the id of the tooltip you want to the variable
  $('#tooltip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).show();
  $('#tooltip-container').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
 }, function(){
  $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});
 });

Comment: fyi, you said nothing about needing help with the ajax side of things. To fade the tooltip in, just use the `.fadeIn()` jquery method. To show a loading.gif image, you should just include that in the html of `#tooltip-container`. In the first part of the hover event, you would `.show()` it, and in the callback to the `.load()` or `$.ajax()` method you use, you would hide it. If that isn't enough info, you should really post a new question because that's totally different than what you are asking about here.

Comment: Working very smoothly nice

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the existing jQuery tooltip plugins and their source to see how they do it. We use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) which works well and has [AJAX support](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax) (note that this demo is set-up to require you to click rather than hover to show the tooltip).

Comment: I looked at that,but I  have a static tooltips.html that holds all the tooltip information and each tooltip needs to be called via it's id e.g. #tip1, #tip2 etc etc - qtip uses individual files for each tooltip it seems?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the CSS property `position: absolute` on your tooltip container element.

The exact position for the tooltip container element depends on the values for `top` and `left` CSS properties (or on `bottom` and `right`, or on any other combination of the four properties). These values should be computed from the position of the currently hovered item.

Comment: This wouldn't work...as just using css would show the tip in the same position...rather than next to each link you hover over.... ?

Comment: He's talking about setting the values via JS, after having "computed" the values of the "currently hovered item" via JS as well. It's basically what my answer says as well, just in fewer words :)

Answer (score 0):

You should append the tooltip-container to tippyrtrip element with:

```
.appendTo()

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){ 
    var tooltipId = this.hash;  
    $('#tooltip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).show().appendTo($(this)); 
}, function(){ 
    $('#tooltip-container').hide(); 
});}); 
</script>
```