# position top in Jquery TipTip is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codeigniter

when i am trying to make it appear at the top of the content its not working properly,
i am using default position to make it appear at top. can anyone suggest me what can i do to fix it.

```
function price_breakdown_tooltip() {

$(".proposal_table_price_breakdown_tiptip").tipTip({   delay :200,
        maxWidth : "200px",
        defaultPosition: "right",
        
        content: function (e) {
          
          setTimeout( function(){
         currentXhr = $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/getProposalPriceBreakdown') ?>',
                        type:'post',
                        data:{proposalId:price_breakdown_tiptip_proposal_id},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#tiptip_content').html(response);
                            //console.log('ffffggg')
                        }
                    });
                },200);
                    return 'Loading...';
                }
    });
};
```

you can see in the image what problem i am facing when i am using position top [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5i2E.png)

Comment: Can you make a snippet on SO? Can you show your HTML and CSS? Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597769/how-to-set-top-position-using-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744928/in-jquery-how-can-i-set-top-left-properties-of-an-element-with-position-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom jQuery Tooltip: How to position it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111869/custom-jquery-tooltip-how-to-position-it)